# Configurar CardView no RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-adapter

Tenho um `RecyclerView` e utilizo com `CardView`, o problema é que em uma versão do android a visualização é diferente da outra. Gostaria que a visualização do android 9.0 ficasse igual ao do 4.3.

Android 4.3 visualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Android 9.0 visulaização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

XML do `CardView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/botao_menu_normal"
            android:padding="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLinhaCidade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Cidade"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

XML do `RecyclerView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textoCidade">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Tente remover o layout_margin do RelativeLayout e colocar um layout_padding no CardView

Comment: Funcionou não, deu o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui achar, é só colocar `cardUseCompatPadding` no CardView com `true`.